# Adding UriMapper for WindowsPhone in Universal Application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm struggling creating an universal app out of an existing windows phone 8.1 app. I used the AssociationUriMapper as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_URIassociations) and I can't find a way to use this in the universal app. The `System.Windows.Navigation` namespace does not exist and therefore I can't override the `UriMapperBase`.

Anyone know where this goes wrong and what I have to do to keep the functionality even in an universal app (*without offering the same feature to windows 8.1 app*)?

Comment: What is your app trying to do?

Comment: I'd like to launch the WindowsPhone-App by calling a specific uri from a website. Prior to Universal App I achieved this by using the `AssociationUriMapper` as described in the link in my question.

Comment: Have you followed the [Windows 8.1 method from the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh779670.aspx)?

Comment: @NeilTurner Thanks! Looked for an article like that for ages - now that it's found, my question seems kind of stupid. But I swear I tried everything to find that information...

Comment: No probs, lots of changes in WP8.1, etc - we're all still looking for the 'correct' info. I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How apps handle Uris on launch has changed a lot since Windows Phone 8. Previously, the app would get passed a Uri which require a lot of parsing to be of any use - hence the need for a UriMapper, which Microsoft provides.

For Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 8.1 (ie. Universal XAML apps), app activation is handled (by  OpenFilePicker, ShareTarget, Protocol, etc) is handled by the OnActivated method...

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)
    {
        ProtocolActivatedEventArgs eventArgs = args as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;

    // TODO: Handle URI activation
    // The received URI is eventArgs.Uri.AbsoluteUri
    }
}
```

Source: [official MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh779670.aspx)

After determining the `ActivationKind` and casting to the right EventArgs type, it's then just a matter of parsing the parameters of the data.

There's also an [example Universal app on that page](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Association-Launching-535d2cec) which details a few of these scenarios.

Comment: Thanks! Very informative even in addition to the MSDN. Thank you as well for not only posting a link :)

Comment: @malte thanks, navigation & lifecycle is *really* different in WP8.1 - I'm still getting used to it myself :)